# Using Case When to Group Users into Buckets with overlapping data in same column?

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark-sql, case

I am looking to bucket users into three distinct categories based on a transaction type column.

1. Web Users
2. Store Users
3. Mixed Users

I have the following columns in my table:

user_id | transactionType | ticketNum | saleAmount

Goal:
I would like to group user_id's saleAmount after identifying whether they are a web user, store user, or mixed user. Currently, transactionType column displays data as web or instore in a separate row for each purchase.

Code Tried:

```
cache table service_bucket as
select user_id,
case
when transactionType= 'WEB' AND 'STORE' then "MIXED USER"
when transactionType = 'WEB' then "WEB USER"
when transactionType = 'STORE' then "STORE USER"
else "Mixed user"  end as serviceBucket, count(distinct ticketNum) as tixCount, sum(Quantity) as purchaseQuant

from base_table
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

The issue seems to be that my code is parsing through each individual row rather than looking through the column for a given user_id. Resulting in multiple rows for each user and none ending up as "Mixed User".

Unwanted Output Example:

| user_id | serviceBucket | tixCount | purchaseQuant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5555 | Web User | 8 | 7 |
| 5555 | Store User | 4 | 7 |
| 5557 | Web User | 4 | 7 |

Desired Output:

| user_id | serviceBucket | tixCount | purchaseQuant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5555 | Mixed User | 12 | 14 |
| 5557 | Web User | 4 | 7 |

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen reasoning below

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the user type column also needs to be aggregated:

```sql
CREATE TABLE service_bucket AS
SELECT user_id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN transactionType = 'WEB' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
                 COUNT(CASE WHEN transactionType = 'STORE' THEN 1 END) > 0
            THEN 'MIXED USER'
            WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN transactionType = 'WEB' THEN 1 END) > 0
            THEN 'WEB'
            ELSE 'STORE'
       END AS serviceBucket
       COUNT(DISTINCT ticketNum) AS tixCount,
       SUM(Quantity) AS purchaseQuant
FROM base_table
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I noticed that my count version was wrong. Tried applying yours and i'm met with a syntax error on row 3. "Parse Exception: mismatched input 'COUNT'...